# Powershell -invokesql with character parameter

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, quoting, invoke-sqlcmd

I have code that reads an excel file and searches the value in the sql database. This is a part of the code:

```
    for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
    { 
        $name = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowName+$i,$colName).text 
        $mail = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowMail+$i,$colMail).text 
        #test   $Query = ‘ SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where value = ‘ + “‘” +$mail + “‘”
        $Query = ‘ SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where id = 3’ 

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $DatabaseServerName -Database $Database -Username $Uid -Password $Pwd -query $Query   -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Host ("My Name is: "+$name)
        Write-Host ("My mail is: "+$mail)
        Write-Host $query
    }
    #close excel file
    $objExcel.quit()
```

If I query with a number `(SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where id = 3)`, it goes ok:

```
id           : 3
className    : PersonBase
keyValue     : 3
typeCd       : 6
value        : karen.g@hotmail.com
description  :
usermodify   :
datemodify   :
My Name is: G Karen
My mail is: karen.g@hotmail.com
 SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where id = 3
```

If I execute with the query :

```
$Query = ‘ SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where value = ‘ + “‘” +$mail + “‘”
```

I get this error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near '''.
>        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure , Line 1.
>       At line:8 char:1
>       + Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $DatabaseServerName -Database $Database ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

When I debug, to me, the output looks fine. I Can paste it onto the server and the select statement works fine:

```
My Name is: G Karen
My mail is: karen.g@hotmail.com
 SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where value = 'karen.g@hotmail.com'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PowerShell happily accepts Unicode (non-ASCII-range) quotation marks** instead of the usual, ASCII-range ones - see this answer

For instance, as in your code:

- `‘` (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+2018`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018)) can be used in lieu of the ASCII-range  `'` (APOSTROPHE, [`U+0027`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27)) , aka *single quote*.
- `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c)) can be used in lieu of the ASCII-range `"` (QUOTATION MARK, [`U+0022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22)), aka *double quote*.

By contrast, I suspect, **SQL Server does *not* suspect these substitutions**, so you'll have to **use ASCII-range `'` and `"` for quotation marks *embedded* in your queries**.

Therefore, the immediate fix is:

```
$Query = ‘ SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where value = ‘ + “'” +$mail + “'”
```

Note how only the characters *inside* `“...”` were changed from `‘` to `'`; the outer quoting, which is interpreted - and removed - *by PowerShell* can keep using the non-ASCII-range quotes.

---

However, you can **more simply use an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`)** with *embedded* variable references:

```
$Query = " SELECT  * FROM dbo.tbl1 where value = '$mail'"
```

Note that I've also switched the outer double quotes to their ASCII-range versions.
**It is generally better even in PowerShell to stick with the usual, ASCII-range quotation marks**, lest problems arise due to character encoding when sharing code.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. Putting my code into notepad instead of word did the trick.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked, @Nancy. A good editor to use for PowerShell is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell). Also, allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment.